# Puppet agent 3.8.1 installation failing on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, puppet, gnupg

Puppet agent version 3.8.1 installation failing on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
root@ip-XX-XXX-XX-XXX:/tmp# curl -k https://puppet.XXXXXX.com:8140/packages/current/install.bash | LANG=en_US.UTF-8 bash -s agent:certname=`/root/.aws/my_puppet_node_name.py`

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100 12584  100 12584    0     0   113k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  114k

checking hfjEnv-Name-cap-project-cap-role-cap-stage

setting nodename "dev-deploytest-api-hco-api-api-deploytest-20160711144459-e0eaf60b-91a1-413f-a92c-c4f897f5f892"

W: GPG error: https://puppet.XXXXXX.com:8140 ./ Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1468001658

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

apt-transport-https is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 89 not upgraded.

OK

W: GPG error: https://puppet.XXXXXX.com:8140 ./ Release: The following 
signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1468001658

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

The following extra packages will be installed:

  pe-augeas pe-facter pe-hiera pe-libyaml pe-mcollective pe-mcollective-common

  pe-openssl pe-puppet pe-puppet-enterprise-release pe-ruby pe-ruby-augeas

  pe-ruby-ldap pe-ruby-rgen pe-ruby-shadow pe-ruby-stomp pe-rubygem-deep-merge

  pe-rubygem-net-ssh pe-virt-what

The following NEW packages will be installed:

  pe-agent pe-augeas pe-facter pe-hiera pe-libyaml pe-mcollective

  pe-mcollective-common pe-openssl pe-puppet pe-puppet-enterprise-release

  pe-ruby pe-ruby-augeas pe-ruby-ldap pe-ruby-rgen pe-ruby-shadow

  pe-ruby-stomp pe-rubygem-deep-merge pe-rubygem-net-ssh pe-virt-what

0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 89 not upgraded.

Need to get 9,832 kB of archives.

After this operation, 54.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.

WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!

  pe-puppet-enterprise-release pe-virt-what pe-augeas pe-libyaml pe-openssl

  pe-ruby pe-rubygem-deep-merge pe-hiera pe-ruby-stomp pe-mcollective-common

  pe-mcollective pe-facter pe-ruby-rgen pe-ruby-shadow pe-rubygem-net-ssh

  pe-ruby-augeas pe-ruby-ldap pe-puppet pe-agent

E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes

/tmp/tmp.PMh6SRUyUm: line 85: /opt/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory

/tmp/tmp.PMh6SRUyUm: line 86: /opt/puppet/bin/facter: No such file or directory

/tmp/tmp.PMh6SRUyUm: line 86: /opt/puppet/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

/tmp/tmp.PMh6SRUyUm: line 86: /opt/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory

/tmp/tmp.PMh6SRUyUm: line 52: /opt/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory

/tmp/tmp.PMh6SRUyUm: line 91: /opt/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory

/tmp/tmp.PMh6SRUyUm: line 58: /opt/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory

/tmp/tmp.PMh6SRUyUm: line 58: /opt/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory

/tmp/tmp.PMh6SRUyUm: line 58: /opt/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory

/tmp/tmp.PMh6SRUyUm: line 58: /opt/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory

Error running install script /tmp/tmp.PMh6SRUyUm

root@ip-XX-XXX-XX-XXX:/tmp# apt-key list

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg

--------------------

pub   1024D/437D05B5 2004-09-12

uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

sub   2048g/79164387 2004-09-12

pub   1024D/FBB75451 2004-12-30

uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/C0B21F32 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/EFE21092 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/4BD6EC30 2010-07-10 [expired: 2016-07-08]
uid                  Puppet Labs Release Key (Puppet Labs Release Key) <info@puppetlabs.com>

root@ip-XX-XXX-XX-XXX:/tmp#
```

Answer (score 5):

Temporary workaround:

> wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/pubkey.gpg
>
> apt-key add pubkey.gpg

..and proceed to install the agent.

Comment: change that to https, and I'll give it a +1

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the expired key as well, and adding the new key to the keyring didn't help(though I'm pretty sure it did work before).
Even after I deliberately removed expired key(with apt-key del), the installation script retrieved it again from the master.  I had to tweak the installation script on the master node to install the agent.
In the file `/opt/puppet/packages/public/3.3.2/ubuntu-14.04-amd64.bash` on the master node:

```
1. I commented out the call of import_gpg_key function

2. Then, I added  --force-yes to the apt-get install -y
```

The agent was installed after that.
Obviously, it is a poor way, so I would be glad, if somebody pointed out what I'm missing.